# jackson marshalling result put in a map - Strange behavior

Tags: java, dictionary, jackson

I had this code in production

```
final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put(FIELDTRACES, new ObjectMapper().writer().writeValueAsString(dlcTransformer.toEntityList(vo.getFieldTraces())));
```

which was failing in some case (when the "vo" object was retrieved from a deserialized JMS message): the put operation was not adding anything to the map.

After various tests I finished with this which seems to fix the problem :

```
final String fieldTraces = new ObjectMapper().writer().writeValueAsString(dlcTransformer.toEntityList(vo.getFieldTraces()));
parameters.put(FIELDTRACES, fieldTraces);
```

How can a temporary variable change anything to the behavior ?

The jackson mapper comes from `jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10`

here is `ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString()` implementation

```
public String writeValueAsString(Object value)
    throws IOException, JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException
{        
    // alas, we have to pull the recycler directly here...
    SegmentedStringWriter sw = new SegmentedStringWriter(_jsonFactory._getBufferRecycler());
    _configAndWriteValue(_jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(sw), value);
    return sw.getAndClear();
}
```

before I try to sacrifice a chicken, does someone have an idea ^^ ?

Comment: Well, introducing a local variable should not make any effect. How exactly it is failing? An exception occurs? A side note is that'd rather share the object mapper instance since it is [thread safe](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQThreadSafety) and quite expensive to create.

Comment: thanks for advice, it is failing by returning null, whereas inspecting the result in a debugger return a well-formed json string

Comment: Which Jackson version you are using? Is the instance of dlcTransformer thread safe?

Comment: jackson 1.9.10, yes Transformer is thread safe

Comment: Have you tried the latest stable 1.X Jackson?

Comment: Thanks but the question is just about understanding how the add of the temporary variable can fix the problem, something i absolutely can't understand in the actual state of my knowledge

Comment: OK. Is the problem always reproducible when you are not using the temporary variable?

Comment: only when the vo object comes from JMS queue

Comment: there is nothing logical here, transformation resulting entity is always correctly valuated, so there is absolutely no reason than the json marshalling fails in one case and not in other, let alone than the temp var fixes this

Comment: That is weird. Are running you application under a Spring or AOP container? Is the object returned from JMS is of a real type or is it a some sort of dynamic proxy?

Comment: Yes Spring AOP is over-used, there are a bunch of proxies around every object, good though, i will dig this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55893/discussion-between-alexey-gavrilov-and-gab).